# Subquery SQL Count function

Tags: sql, count

```
Jurisdiction      Route
------------      -----
Portland           65
Portland           55
Cornelius          75
Cornelius          75
Cornelius          75
```

How can I count the number of routes for cornelius? The answer is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY Jurisdiction, Route 
WHERE Jurisdiction = 'Cornelius'
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Route) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY Jurisdiction 
WHERE Jurisdiction = 'Cornelius'
```

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to use `COUNT()` and `DISTINCT`

```
select count(distinct Jurisdiction) total, Jurisdiction
from table1
where Jurisdiction = 'Cornelius'
group by Jurisdiction
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fead7/6)